# Using automotive relay in various applications

Tags: relay, automotive

Could an automotive relay be used to switch a AC or DC voltage higher than 12Vdc ?
For example, I have a relay of this type: [image: automotive relay]

Could this type of relay be used for switching 5A at 35Vac ?

All the information that I found about this relay is listed in the uploaded screenshot.

Comment: What do the ratings say?

Comment: 30/40A at 14Vdc and 500VAC dielectric strength between open contacts

Comment: So no mention of an AC switching rating. I wouldn't use them for AC in anything more serious than a hobby project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

(in the general case and for anything more or less serious)

Maybe...

(depending on the project importance and what will happen if the relay fails.)

Bear in mind that the relay may as well fail by catching fire.

---

The interesting thing about the automotive relays is that a at least some of them have contacts rated only for 14V even if the coil is 24V and the obvious purpose of the relay in question is to be used in 24V automotive setup.